# Can I use python code in flutter project?

Tags: python, flutter, plugins

Im working on a project proposal for a mobile app and it contains some image processing portion(python is good at it) so i was wondering if i can use some python code in the flutter project with some plugins etc. (i have selected flutter for the app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  image processing you can make use of cloud functions, there you can upload your specific image processing code and from flutter you can directly call those functions
Check out serverless computing
Or you can have python backend running somewhere for all your processing tasks

You can also check https://pub.dev/packages/starflut this Repo if you want to integrate your image processing in your app